# How to deploy a Java EE application on vanilla Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, ejb, apache-tomee, openejb

### The problem

I have a legacy Java EE application which I have to deploy on a vanilla Tomcat instance. I cannot change the configuration of the Tomcat instance, only deploy WAR's to it.

The application uses a lot of `@Stateless` and `@SessionScoped` beans as well as JSF. [This page](http://openejb.apache.org/comparison.html) seems to suggest that I can use TomEE for running my application on Tomcat.

The problem is that TomEE seems to require changes to the Tomcat installation, which I cannot do.

### What I have tried so far

I have successfully used [EJBContainer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/embeddable/EJBContainer.html) to initiate the EJB's and this part seems to work correctly. I do however have trouble integrating this with JSF and it's `FacesServlet`.

### The question

Is it possible to bundle a WAR with all the TomEE functionality such that I can deploy the application without changing the Tomcat installation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, theoretically it is, but I personally have no experience doing it. The documentation is here: http://tomee.apache.org/installation-drop-in-war.html I'm sure there are a few caveats you should be aware of, but good luck!

Also, if you were to provide more details about your environment, your constraints and why you cannot change the things as is, we may be able to find an alternative path that could help out.

Comment: The link that you provided shows how to install TomEE on a vanilla Tomcat using a WAR file. It doesn't show how to bundle the Java EE functionality inside an application WAR file. The reason why I want to support a vanilla Tomcat is that we are deploying to AWS Elasticbeanstalk.

Comment: There are no 'JEE Bundlers' that I'm aware of for any server. The TomEE standalone installation certainly does not accomplish this. Two suggestions, check out Jelastic as an alternative. The other is to keep using the ejb lite container, but manually add the jsf filter to your web.xml.